# Should one do data analysis by fake data?

Tags: ethics

Is it ethical to use fake data in data science? Namely, I have heard two opinions.

1. First collect data or get it somewhere, do the analysis and report, and sent the report to the customer.
2. Do data analysis by dummy data, show it to potential customers, get the real data, change dummy data to the real data, do the analysis and report and send it to the customer.

Comment: There is difference between fake and dummy data.

Comment: what is this for, an example of your work for interview?

Comment: Garbage in garbage out. Your analysis is as good as the input data you start with. If that is bad how can your analysis be good?

Comment: What is the purpose of this analysis? Do you tell the potential customer "These numbers aren't real, but this is the type of analysis we could do for you!", or are you lying and telling them that the dummy data is actually real? One is acceptable, the other is not.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide context. It might be highly unethical to present results from fake data, just as it is to present fake results. But indeed many people use "simulated data" for several valid reasons, and add the require notice warnings with results derived from them.

Comment: If your goal is to showcase your analytical capabilities, why not use real, publicly available data? There’s plenty of it out there, across all different domains and it will look a lot more impressive than showing fake insights.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It very much depends on what the purpose of this data report is, and how honest you are in your report.

The only way I could imagine using dummy data to be acceptable is if you are honest and upfront about saying, "Hey, these numbers aren't real, but this is an example of the type of analysis we could do for you!" In this instance your primary goal is to talk about your process and capabilities, and the numbers really aren't important.

However, if your report tries to pass off the dummy data as real data, and your message is "Look at these numbers - our results are great!", that is **completely unethical**. Not only unethical, I would be very surprised if this were not illegal in many jurisdictions.

**Absolutely do not, under any circumstances, use dummy data in place of real data unless you are very transparent that you are doing so.**

Answer (score 4):

If your intent is to present a hypothetical example, and you clearly state that it is hypothetical only with mocked up data, then yes--it's ethical.

Or perhaps it's to demonstrate a new report where the data is irrelevant, then I see no issue.

If, on the other hand, deception is intended, I can't imagine how you expect any answer other than "No, it's not ethical".